# How to get Awstats to ignore me

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, logging, awstats

I am using awstats to log my server traffic and am very pleased. One problem is that I am traveling a lot and I do not want my traffic counted in awstats.

Do you have any good idea on how I can ignore my visits?

My first thought is to somehow use cookies. I have added a new logformat to my apache server according to http://www.crumpeta.com/adding_cookie_information_to_apache_log_files. Is it possible to filter cookies within awstats in order to ignore me?

Comment: If one person's browsing is significant enough to skew the stats dramatically, why care about them?

Comment: Thats true, but even if it is some small ratio why should I have my own visits counted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be adding a second vhost that only you use that doesn't log traffic to the main log that awstats reads.

Comment: This is a good idea, but not an optimal idea. For the moment I can have as many virtual hosts as I want but what if I start to use a web hotel or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a special config in your awstats config file, il order to ignore specific accesses.

Use something like :

LogFile="grep -v YOUCOOKIESTRING /var/log/apache2/access.log |"

In your /etc/awstats/awstats.yoursite.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you browse from a static or dynamic IP? If it's a static IP (most business grade internet connections will have this), have a look at the *SkipHosts* parameter in your awstats configuration file.

Comment: I do not have a static IP, this is a personal project that I am working with on my spear time.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up and additional VirtualHost with the same DocumentRoot and related parameters as your main site but with a different ServerName. To work, the internal links in your own site would need to be local.

You can extract the related log entries from a single set of log files or set up different ErrorLog and CustomLog for your new VirtualHost.